# Bind ObservableCollection<XmlNode> to combobox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm trying to bind a combobox to a ObservableCollection.When the form is displayed the combobox is empty.The same code with ObservableCollection of type string works perfectly. I've got a feeling that my XPath is wrong. Any suggestions are welcome:

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemParameters, XPath=InnerXml/name,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Height="24"  />
```

**ObservableCollection XmlNode :**

```
public ObservableCollection<XmlNode> _itemParameters = new ObservableCollection<XmlNode>();
public ObservableCollection<XmlNode> ItemParameters
{
    get { return _itemParameters; }
    set { _itemParameters = value; }
}
```

The combobox should display the **name** attribute of each XmlNode in the collection:
[image]

**Update:**

I've tried using DisplayMemberPath in two different ways, but the combobox still contains no data:

```
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding XPath=name}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemParameters}"
DisplayMemberPath="{Binding XPath=InnerXml/name}" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemParameters}"
```

**Solution:**

This did the trick, hope it helps someone else as well:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="@name" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemParameters}"
```

Comment: You should use `@name` in your xpath since you are interested in the *attribute* `name`, not the *element* name, as stated at http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you are setting `Path` and `XPath` at the same time, which are conficting properties, secondly you bind the `ItemsSource`, which has nothing to do with what you want to show *inside* the item. Either use [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) or an [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) for that, the `ItemsSource` should just be bound to `ItemParameters`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer,I believe I'm not setting both Path and Xpath at the same time...If you look at the XAML you'll see that only XPath is set. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Deni: `ItemParameters` is set to the Path property, it's implicit

Comment: @Deni: In general in [markup extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx) unnamed parameters are passed to the contructor of the underlying class, `Binding` has a [constructor which takes a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597578.aspx) that is used as the `Binding.Path`.